# Update two forms with one submit

Tags: python, django, forms

I have one form and formset. I want to update them at the same time (with the same submit). Forms are rendered correct (with good data), but updated data is not written to db. Nether forms validation works. When it is one form it works perfect. Where could be the problem?

My view class:

```
class EventAdminPage(UpdateView):
    form_class = CreateEventForm
    second_form_class = modelformset_factory(EventTime, form = EventTimeForm, min_num=1, validate_min=True, extra=3)
    model = Event
    template_name = 'eventAdmin.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EventAdminPage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        event_times = EventTime.objects.filter(event = self.object).exclude(start_time = None)
        context['participants'] = Participant.objects.filter(event = self.object)
        context['event_times'] = EventTime.objects.filter(event = self.object).exclude(start_time = None)
        context['event_time_formset_helper'] = event_time_formset_helper = EventTimeFormsetHelper()
        context['formset'] = self.second_form_class(prefix='eventtime', queryset=event_times)
        context['form'] = self.form_class(instance = self.object)
        return context

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        event_times = EventTime.objects.filter(event = self.object).exclude(start_time = None)
        if 'update_event_form' in request.POST:
            form = self.form_class(instance=self.get_object())
            formset = self.second_form_class(queryset=event_times)
            if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
                form.save()
                formset.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/event-admin-%s' %self.kwargs['event_id']) 
            else:
                return self.render_to_response(
                    self.get_context_data(form=form, formset=formset))

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.object = Event.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['event_id'])
        form = self.form_class
        formset = self.second_form_class
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object, form=form, formset=formset)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = Event.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['event_id'])
        return obj
```

Comment: You don't seem to be saving the forms anywhere.

Comment: Sorry I copied bad code, but anyway it never goes under `if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid()`

Comment: OK, but now you're never passing `request.POST` to those forms.

Comment: `context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.POST or None, instance = self.object)` doesn't help

Comment: No, it wouldn't. You need to do it in the code where you're instantiating them on POST.

Comment: `form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=self.get_object())
   formset = self.second_form_class(request.POST, queryset=event_times)` I changed to this but now I am getting "[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
"